# Retrieve a python list from external python file(Django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, stdout

I'm trying to retrieve a python list that generates from an external python file(`algorithm.py`). In `algorithm.py` has a set of functions that used to generate a python list. There is no issue with `algorithm.py` file and it generates the python list as I expect. I followed the below steps to get the python list which generates in `algorithm.py` into `views.py`.

1.) Pass a variable(`lec_name`) from a function in `views.py` to `algorithm.py` and retrieve the output by using `stdout` as the below statement.

```
lec_name = request.POST['selected_name']
result = run([sys.executable,'//Projects//altg//algorithm.py',lec_name], shell=False, stdout=PIPE)
```

2.) And then when I `print(result.stdout)`, I receive the output(*the python list which I expect*) as an `array of byte` as below.

```
b"[['0', 'Subject01(IS0001)', 'Z Hall(65)', 'Thursday 10:00-12:00'], ['1', 'Subject02(IS42255)', 'N Hall(90)', 'Wednesday 08:00-10.00']]\r\n"
```

3.) Then I used `print((result.stdout).strip())` to remove `\r\n` and It gives output as below.

```
b"[['0', 'Subject01(IS0001)', 'Z Hall(65)', 'Thursday 10:00-12:00'], ['1', 'Subject02(IS42255)', 'N Hall(90)', 'Wednesday 08:00-10.00']]"
```

This gives the python list which I expect as an `array of byte` So what I need, retrieve the output(*the python list which I expect*) as a python `list`. How can I solve this? I tried lot of things, but none succeeded. I'm using Python 3.7.4, Django 3.0.1

Comment: Yeah. That helps me. Thank you @Joe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `literal_eval`, which *[Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python expression](https://kite.com/python/docs/ast.literal_eval)*:

```
import ast
data  = b"[['0', 'Subject01(IS0001)', 'Z Hall(65)', 'Thursday 10:00-12:00'], ['1', 'Subject02(IS42255)', 'N Hall(90)', 'Wednesday 08:00-10.00']]"

data_list = ast.literal_eval(data.decode())
print(type(data_list)) # output: <class 'list'>
print(data_list) # output: [['0', 'Subject01(IS0001)', 'Z Hall(65)', 'Thursday 10:00-12:00'], ['1', 'Subject02(IS42255)', 'N Hall(90)', 'Wednesday 08:00-10.00']]
```